# How to redirect user after login YII?

Tags: yii

I have got this action for login:

```
    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_REQUEST['ajax']) && isset($_REQUEST['users']))
    {
            //echo CActiveForm::validate($model);

            $model->attributes=$_REQUEST['users'];

            $result = array();

            if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            {
                    // MONGO - START
                    DPoints::app()->dailyLogin(Yii::app()->user->id); 
                    // MONGO - END

                    $result['status'] = 'success';
                    $user = users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
                    if($user->role == 'admin')
                    {
                            $result['url'] = Yii::app()->createUrl('/admin/questions');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $result['url'] = Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/dashboard'); 
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    $result['status'] = 'failed';
                    $errors = $model->getErrors();
                    $result['errormessage'] = $errors;              
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
          //  $this->redirect('http://www.teddfel.hu/question/igaz-hogy-ebben-az-evben-nem-lesz-igazi-nyarunk_11289');
            return;
    }
```

I have read somewhere I should uis`$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);` to redirect the user. But in my example where should I use that redirection for user? I would like to redirect the user after login was accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an AJAX request you will not be able to force redirect from the controller. Instead, you need to process response using the same AJAX. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    // implementation goes here
    success: function(response) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(response);
        if (result.status === 'success') {
            document.location.href = result.url;
        }
    }
})
```

And also, Yii provides you better way to check if it's an AJAX request by doing that:

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you should redirect everywhere after `if($model->validate() && $model->login())`, at the end of those if, that are non-ajax in case you don't want.

Since that means that user succesfully logged in.

```
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
      {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
        {
          $this->redirect('http://www.google.com');
        }
      }
```

Comment: I tried to put my code after `if($model->validate() && $model->login())` ... But it dont do anything. And it may use ajax. Is that a problem? It just redirect me to homepage.

Comment: Try removing the "echo json_encode....", I don't know if the redirect uses headers. If it uses headers, then you shouldn't echo anything before them.